# Entity ramework Code first approach

Tags: entity-framework-6

Using code first approach during development phase the table schema will be created based on model changes by doing Add-migration/Update-Database in package console  which is good and clear ,My question is In production with the existing data how the model changes will  reflect on table changes  and what is the process involved to restore the existing data?